# Missing a message from TCPClient

Tags: python

I am new into Python and socket programming. This is my TCPClient code.

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence :')
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print('From server', modifiedSentence.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

The message that should be displayed when I run the code should be :

1. Input lowercase sentence : message  (example sentence)
2. From server MESSAGE

But only 1. was displayed, 2. wasnt even there.

Can someone point out my mistake?

This is my TPCServer code anyway.

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((serverName, serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

print('The server is ready to receive.')

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
```

Comment: Consider that `recv` waits to fill a buffer of 1024 bytes (the number that you determined), so it will be waiting until your server sends 1024 bytes. You'll need to send 1024 bytes from the server for your client to continue its execution.

Comment: You want your server to return the message it received, but in uppercase? Your server receives but it does nothing after that right now. Your buffersize of 1024 is ok because it is actually the maximum size of the buffer. Anything less than 1024 bytes will be output withouth problems.

Comment: Ohhh I got it now, thank youu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server side:

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind((serverName, serverPort))

serverSocket.listen(1)

print('The server is ready to receive.')

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    if sentence:
        print(sentence.decode())
        sentence = sentence.upper()
        print(sentence)
        connectionSocket.send(sentence)
```

Client side:

```
from socket import *
serverName = 'localhost'
serverPort = 12000
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)

clientSocket.connect((serverName, serverPort))

sentence = input('Input lowercase sentence :')
clientSocket.send(sentence.encode())
modifiedSentence = clientSocket.recv(1024)

print('From server', modifiedSentence.decode())

clientSocket.close()
```

This will output to the client:

```
Input lowercase sentence :teste
From server TESTE
```

Comment: The server should probably close the connection after it sends the response.